# Understanding 3D Models and Nodes in Libgdx

Tags: java, animation, 3d, libgdx

I am trying to get a better understanding of the `Model`s and their `Node`hierarchy in `Libgdx`.
As much as i understood, a `Model` is made of many Child`Node`s, which can contain other `Node`s as well. Each node has a `Vector3 translation` describing its position, `Vector3 scale`, describing its scale and `Quaternion rotation` describing its rotation, all relative to the parent `Node` or `Model`. The `Matrix4 gloabalTransform` describes the same, but relative to the world they are in.

Now if i think about games like `Garrys Mod`, where the `Model`s of the `Player`s can move parts of the model dynamically (for example if they lie on an edge after they died their upper body can hang down the wall), i can only think about, that they modify the single `Node`s at runtime, in their source code.
Now my questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Do i have the possibility to create the `Node`s in `Blender` (lets say 1 `Node` is the left lower leg, 1 `Node` is the left upper leg...) and get and change them at runtime by using (for example) `modelInstance.getNode("leftLowerLeg").translation.set(Vector3 position)`, or are they created and named automatically, depending on the shape, facecount...?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would say that you are describing the scene graph there but not knowing libgdx that may not be the case. Moving separate parts of a model would usually be done with animations applied to the mesh but again no knowledge of libgdx. Blender yes you could create models in this way and you can view the hierarchy in the screens panel which includes how your materials are attached.

Comment: So in Blender you can "split" your `Model` in different `Node`s and give them names?

Comment: Well you could build up a model made of constituent parts which can all be named yes. And if you already have a model yes you can split sections apart to create separate meshes which will require naming. However I don't think that is the best option and you should attempt one model(mesh) and create animations for movements you want.

Comment: Yea i know you can add `Animation`s and i know how to use them in Libgdx. But for this dynamic behaivor (i actually don't want to use it i am not that experianced yet) `Animation`s won't help. So i just wonder how would this work in Libgdx. It would also help me to have a basic understanding about what those `Node`s are exactly, as the docs only say "A model is a hierarchical representation of nodes. In practice this means that a model contains an array of nodes and each node contains also an array of nodes." but out of this i don'T know from where do they come, how big are they...

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html looking at that it appears that the concept of node is that of scene graph. Your model can be made of parts (MeshPart) and each separate part is a child of a node. Having a separate node means you can apply transforms to it thus moving it independently from any other model part. So it appears that you do want to construct your model as separate parts and load those parts in a hierarchy of nodes to suit your needs. Keep a reference to the node you want to move independently and apply transforms.

Comment: So every `Node` is a `MeshPart`? And the parent `Node`s contatin many `Node`s (`MeshPart`s)? And can i give those `Node`s a name in Blender? So i can have a `Node leftLowerLag` and translate/rotate its child `Note`s to make only this leg move? Would the name in libgdx be the same as in Blender?

Comment: Node can "contain" a MeshPart (i.e. MeshPart is child of Node) Nodes can contain other nodes. take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph for scene graph terminology.

Comment: Hang on the docs for Model say "A model represents a 3D assets. It stores a hierarchy of nodes. A node has a transform and optionally a graphical part in form of a MeshPart and Material. Mesh parts reference subsets of vertices in one of the meshes of the model. Animations can be applied to nodes, to modify their transform (translation, rotation, scale) over time." Note it says sub set of vertices which implies that the model is one model but you separate them for your needs assigning different sub sets into Nodes.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for this informations. Now the only question left is: Are the `Node`ids the same as the names in `Blender`. But i can easily test this if you don't know it.

Comment: As a guess I would say that the name from Blender is used somewhere but where I don't know.

Comment: This tutorial shows how to use the node hierarchy from the modeling application and the code: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/. Here are two tutorials explaining the node structure and how to use it: http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part1/ (theory) and http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part2/ (practical).

Comment: So if you set a `ModelInstance`s `transform` to the `globalTransform` of the `Node` the `ModelInstance` does only reppresent the `Node` then?

Comment: @Xoppa: I think now i understood. If you create a `ModelInstance` with the `(Model model, String id)` constructor, it "cuts" the `Node` with the given `id` out of the `model` and creates a new instance out of it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [that](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html) it appears that the concept of node is that of scene graph. Your model can be made of parts (MeshPart) and each separate part is a child of a node. Having a separate node means you can apply transforms to it thus moving it independently from any other model part. So it appears that you do want to construct your model as separate parts and load those parts in a hierarchy of nodes to suit your needs. Keep a reference to the node you want to move independently and apply transforms.

Node can "contain" a MeshPart (i.e. MeshPart is child of Node) Nodes can contain other nodes. take a look [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) for scene graph terminology. Hang on the docs for Model say "A model represents a 3D assets. It stores a hierarchy of nodes. A node has a transform and optionally a graphical part in form of a MeshPart and Material. Mesh parts reference subsets of vertices in one of the meshes of the model. Animations can be applied to nodes, to modify their transform (translation, rotation, scale) over time." Note it says sub set of vertices which implies that the model is one model but you separate them for your needs assigning different sub sets into Nodes.

From Xoppa:

This [tutorial](http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/) shows how to use the node hierarchy from the modeling application.
 Here are two tutorials explaining the node structure and how to use it:

1. [Theory](http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part1/)
2. [Practical](http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part2/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It deffinitly helped me to understand it. As you said you don't know libgdx and so you cannot answer the libgdx specific questions, like the naming of the `Node`s, if it is the same as in Blender... For that i ll leave this question open for some days and then accept it. I will try out those things myself and if i find out something i add it to this answer and accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I am currently working on this exact problem. Nodes can have nodes which can have nodes! You can find a specific node using `ModelInstance.getNode(String NameOfNode);` which returns an object of type Node. These nodes are named what you named the objects in blender.  EG, to get the Right shoulder bone in a model with the bone named `Shoulder_R`, you could do:

```
Node node = myModelInstance.getNode("Shoulder_R");
```

**node** that contains all the information pertaining to that bone, including translation, rotation, scale, and the appropriate transform matrices. I am currently stuck at the point of trying to manipulate these bones while an animation is playing, post the animation controller update.

My desired end result is to manually modify for example where an arm is pointing so its pointing at another object while the animation and model continue to play/move. I hope this helps you in your quest, and if you discover the answer to the remaining part of the mystery, please post back!

Comment: As much as i understood you can modify `Node`s, only as long as they are not used by any `Animation`. So maybe your `Animation` affects the same `Node` you try to change manualy?

Comment: So it turns out, you can modify a body part that is affected by an animation, first by setting the nodes.isAnimated to true, and then manipulating the localtransform.  My issue was resulting from trying to manipulate the globaltransforms, which are derived.  In any case, the same affect can be achieved by manipulating the local transform offsetting the parent node, or the models transform.  End result in my test is a walking robot that can now point his arm at a target vertex while in motion.