# 3D product showcase with libgdx?

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I'm searching for a way to show a 3D object of a product in my android application. It then should be possible for the user to move parts of it depending on an underlying skeleton with some joints. For example this product could be a 3D model of a bicycle where the user can spin the pedals or turn the handlebar (either as touch input or as button click).

I thought of using libgdx as framework but it doesn't seem as libgdx would support joints in 3D object. Or did I just miss it?
So my question: Is it possible to use libgdx for such a project? And if not, is there another lightweight 3d engine / framework which does support those requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx 3d support skinned mesh and joints and animation in 3d, please see libgdx wiki,

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning

also note you should export your objects or animation as fbx and convert it by fbx-convert

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/downloads/fbx-conv/

please use latest nightly not latest release.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/

Comment: Thanks, I also found another tutorial which explains it really good: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/01/19/3D-models-and-animation-from-Blender-to-LibGDX.aspx

What I haven't found out is: Is it possible to pause animations and start them from a specific keyframe? So for example if I have an animation for my bicycle handlebar, can I play half of this animation, pause it and then play it backwards from the keyframe I paused on?

Comment: Yes of course you can, but I actually working on another project heavily and do not remember exactly, use animationDesc or animationController for changing speed to 0 (or even negative) at certain frame. please see api doc for info.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452572/understanding-3d-models-and-nodes-in-libgdx) you can get some informations about the `Model`/`Node` hierarchy in Libgdx. To get some basic understanding i suggest to read the tutorials of [Xoppa](http://blog.xoppa.com/), the creator of the 3D API of Libgx.
Basicly a `Model` is made of [`Node`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html)s, which can contain other `Node`s. So you have a `Node` hierarchy. all the `Node`s have their own positions, scale and positon, you can change.
So it is possible to change every single `Node` of your `Model` at runtime.
But it will be a bit hard to create the `Animation` you want, with code. But its possible :P

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Am I right that if I wanted to create a dynamic animation at runtime (for example turning the handlebar on the bicycle object according to touch inputs), I would have to apply multiple transformations (> 40 per second) on the handlebar node?

Comment: If you want the handlebar to follow the touch/drag, you need to transform it in the `InputProcessor`s method (touchDown or touchDraged or something like that). You need to get the `dx` and `dy` (difference between last touchpos and this touchpos) and according to this you `transform` the handlebar